# How to create an "X" pattern?

Tags: java, c, nested-loops

I want to know how to create the following pattern using `*` and `_` using nested loops.

```
*_______*
__*___* 
____*   
__*___* 
*_______*
```

I am currently trying to do this in Java, but an answer in C will do as well, I can extrapolate the answer.
Here is a pic to better understand the pattern required.

[image]

I understand that I need to have some code to start with , but I cant manage to work out the logic.

Is there any algo/technique that anyone can guide me towards in order to be able to attempt this, some Karnaugh map like technique.

Comment: Can you think of how you’d make just one diagonal of the X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
       if(j==2*i || 8-2*i == j)
          System.out.print("*");
       else if(8-2*i < j && j > 2*i)
           break;
       else
          System.out.print("_");
    }
  System.out.println();
}
```